# Convert the formatted string to array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string-formatting

I have the following string

```
myString = "cat(50),dog(60),pig(70)"
```

I try to convert the above string to 2D array.
The result I want to get is

```
myResult = [['cat', 50], ['dog', 60], ['pig', 70]]
```

I already know the way to solve by using the legacy string method but it is quite complicated. So I don't want to use this approach.

```
# Legacy approach
# 1. Split string by ","
# 2. Run loop and split string by "(" => got the <name of animal>
# 3. Got the number by exclude ")".
```

Any suggestion would appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the re.findall method:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)\((\d+)\)', myString)
[('cat', '50'), ('dog', '60'), ('pig', '70')]
```

If you want a list of lists as noticed by RomanPerekhrest convert it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in re.findall(r'(\w+)\((\d+)\)', myString)]
[['cat', '50'], ['dog', '60'], ['pig', '70']]
```

Comment: should be `[list(t) for t in re.findall(r'(\w+)\((\d+)\)', myString)]`

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using [***re.split()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) function:

```
import re
myString = "cat(50),dog(60),pig(70)"
result = [re.split(r'[)(]', i)[:-1] for i in myString.split(',')]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['cat', '50'], ['dog', '60'], ['pig', '70']]
```

---

`r'[)(]'` - pattern, treats parentheses as delimiters for splitting

`[:-1]` - slice containing all items except the last one(which is empty space `' '`)